# How to make a table to scroll from right to left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple table with an `overflow-x:auto;` feature:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 150%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>d</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>a</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

How can I use the `direction: rtl;` element to make it scroll from right to left when the screen is small?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `direction:rtl` on the parent. Also, you don't need to manually do the RTL in code. Check edited table.

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto; width: 600px; direction: rtl;">
  <table style="width: 700px;">
    <style>
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      td,
      th {
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3px;
      }
    </style>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this CSS Media query:

```
<style>
  /* When max width of the screen is 768px */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    div {
      overflow: scroll;
      direction: rtl;
    }
  }
</style>
```